# Close vote modal thinks I retracted my vote, but the question was closed and then reopened

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, close-dialog, retracted-close-votes

The close modal that is shown for questions you have successfully closed but which have since been reopened is showing the wrong header:

[image: Close vote modal showing 'You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote' at the top for a question I successfully voted to close]

The text says:

> You cannot vote to close again after **retracting your vote**

(emphasis mine)

I suspect this is shown because the system looks at the current state of the post and checks for any current/pending close votes by the user; if the post is open and it finds no pending close vote by the user, it then shows this message at the top.

However, I did not retract my vote. I successfully closed the question with two other users, and it was later reopened by different users.

[image: Image of the timeline page of the post in question, showing I was part of a successful closure, and showing that the post was then reopened]

Can the code checking for this please be fixed to correctly check whether I cast a successful vote or retracted one? I assume it worked correctly at some point in the past, but I don't know what the word is that was shown at that time.

Comment: This must be a new problem. I am fairly confident it used to say that you cannot vote to close twice on the same question.

Comment: Status-reviewed on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376335/1099857